# Выполнение арифметических действий с подсписками списка python

Tags: python, list

Как сделать так, что бы элементы первого столбца умножались на два, а элементы второго столбца умножались на три и результат попадал в новый список списков? Можно ли это сделать средствами list comprehension?

```
a=[[1,2],
  [13,27],
  [18,22],
  [10,11]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][j], end='\t')
    print()
print('__________')



for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i][0]+6, end='\t')
    print(a[i][1]+11, end='\t')
    print()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
b = [[x*2, y*3] for x, y in a]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как же это просто оказывается.